# Android UI DPI Issue - is xxxhdpi resources needed?

Tags: android, user-interface

I am designing an android app for a client. Following the guidelines of Android UI design I have sliced all the icons and images in the following dpi's - xxhdpi, xhdpi, hdpi, mdpi, ldpi.

While the android design guide says they have released **xxxhdpi** also. Is it necessary to include files with 640 dpi(xxxhdpi) with my app?

Does the app loading time depends on this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As per Developer site

*Some devices scale-up the launcher icon by as much as 25%. For example, if your highest density launcher icon image is already extra-extra-high density, the scaling process will make it appear less crisp. So you should provide a higher density launcher icon in the drawable-xxxhdpi directory, which the system uses instead of scaling up a smaller version of the icon.*

*Note: the drawable-xxxhdpi qualifier is necessary only **to provide a launcher icon that can appear larger than usual on an xxhdpi device. You do not need to provide xxxhdpi assets for all your app's images**.*

Check this link for more details http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html